# How to read first N lines of a file?

Tags: python

We have a large raw data file that we would like to trim to a specified size.

How would I go about getting the first N lines of a text file in python? Will the OS being used have any effect on the implementation?

Comment: can I give n as command line argument

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Python 3:

```
with open(path_to_file) as input_file:
    head = [next(input_file) for _ in range(lines_number)]
print(head)
```

Python 2:

```
with open(path_to_file) as input_file:
    head = [next(input_file) for _ in xrange(lines_number)]
print head
```

Here's another way (both Python 2 & 3):

```
from itertools import islice

with open(path_to_file) as input_file:
    head = list(islice(input_file, lines_number))
print(head)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful indeed.  What is the difference between the two? (in terms of performance, required libraries, compatibility etc)?

Comment: I expect the performance to be similar, maybe the first to be slightly faster. But the first one won't work if the file doesn't have at least N lines. You are best to measure the performance against some typical data you will be using it with.

Comment: The with statement works on Python 2.6, and requires an extra import statement on 2.5. For 2.4 or earlier, you'd need to rewrite the code with a try...except block. Stylistically, I prefer the first option, although as mentioned the second is more robust for short files.

Comment: islice is probably faster as it is implemented in C.

Comment: @chrispy, I just tried it out and the second one was faster for the file that I was using as soon as N grows above 20 or so

Comment: Have in mind that if the files have less then N lines this will raise StopIteration exception that you must handle

Comment: why is it the prefered way? Could you explain this in your answer?

Comment: What to do, if there are less than N lines in the file ?

Comment: @krishna222, The version using `islice` will read the whole file if it has less than `N` lines

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder if it's obvious to point out that to have the output in a "proper" format rather than a list it's possible to get that with the statement `for line in head: print line,` instead of `print head`

Comment: Also if you are using Python 3 you would use range(n) rather than xrange()

Comment: it seems like this method combine all columns of the original files, say a `.csv` into a single element of the resultant list, is this true to everyone or just me? How to maintain the original format or let the data was read in DataFrame if it is?

Comment: @JasonGoal, This question/answer isn't concerned with the meaning of the data. For a csv file, the process is similar but you would pass the file through a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, thanks for the explanation,  just figured out how to do this for `.csv` file. `itertools.islice` is the trick, and if people want to explore header of their `.csv`, `DictReader` comes in handy.

Comment: This answer has a VERY BIG drawback, you cannot have files with fewer than N lines, or else it will explode. It should NOT be marked as correct, and all those SO developers who just copy pasted are introducing a bug in their code!

Comment: This is the right way, as it consumes the file as a stream until necessary (doesn't read all the lines).

Answer (score 31):

```py
N = 10
with open("file.txt", "a") as file:  # the a opens it in append mode
    for i in range(N):
        line = next(file).strip()
        print(line)
```

Comment: Why open the file in append mode?

Comment: @AMC I think it is for not deleting the file, but we should use 'r' here instead.

Comment: @Kowalski Append mode is for adding to the file, `r` is indeed the more logical choice, I think.

Comment: @ghostdog74, how can read the next N values ?

Answer (score 28):

If you want to read the first lines quickly and you don't care about performance you can use `.readlines()` which returns list object and then slice the list.

E.g. for the first 5 lines:

```
with open("pathofmyfileandfileandname") as myfile:
    firstNlines=myfile.readlines()[0:5] #put here the interval you want
```

> **Note:** the whole file is read so is **not the best from the performance point of view** but it
>   is easy to use, fast to write and easy to remember so if you want just perform
>   some one-time calculation is very convenient

```
print firstNlines
```

One advantage compared to the other answers is the possibility to select easily the range of lines e.g. skipping the first 10 lines `[10:30]` or the lasts 10 `[:-10]` or taking only even lines `[::2]`.

Comment: The top answer is probably way more efficient, but this one works like a charm for small files.

Comment: Note that this actually reads the whole file into a list first  (myfile.readlines()) and then splices the first 5 lines of it.

Comment: This should be avoided.

Comment: I see no reason to use this, it's not any simpler than the vastly more efficient solutions.

Comment: @AMC thanks for the feedback, I use it in the console for exploring the data when I have to have a quick look to the first lines, it just saves me time in writing code.

Comment: @GM Do you find it faster to type than the solution using `itertools.islice()` ? Of course, that requires an extra module.

Comment: @AMC absolutely with islice you have to import a module and to remember a not very intuitive command, this solution is faster to write and easier to remember the perfect choice for one time operations.

Answer (score 13):

What I do is to call the N lines using `pandas`. I think the performance is not the best, but for example if `N=1000`:

```
import pandas as pd
yourfile = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file.csv',nrows=1000)
```

Comment: Better would be to use the `nrows` option, which can be set to 1000 and the entire file isn't loaded. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html In general, pandas has this and other memory-saving techniques for big files.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just correct it. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: You may also want to add `sep` to define a column delimiter (which shouldn't occur in a non-csv file)

Comment: @Cro-Magnon I cannot find the `pandas.read()` function in the documentation, do you know of any information on the subject?

Answer (score 8):

There is no specific method to read number of lines exposed by file object.

I guess the easiest way would be following:

```
lines =[]
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines.extend(f.readline() for i in xrange(N))
```

Comment: This is something I had actually intended. Though, I though of adding each line to list. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The two most intuitive ways of doing this would be:

1. Iterate on the file line-by-line, and `break` after `N` lines.
2. Iterate on the file line-by-line using the `next()` method `N` times. (This is essentially just a different syntax for what the top answer does.)

Here is the code:

```
# Method 1:
with open("fileName", "r") as f:
    counter = 0
    for line in f:
        print line
        counter += 1
        if counter == N: break

# Method 2:
with open("fileName", "r") as f:
    for i in xrange(N):
        line = f.next()
        print line
```

The bottom line is, as long as you don't use `readlines()` or `enumerate`ing the whole file into memory, you have plenty of options.

Comment: _The bottom line is, as long as you don't use readlines() or enumerateing the whole file into memory, you have plenty of options._ Isn't `enumerate()` lazy?

Answer (score 4):

Based on gnibbler top voted answer (Nov 20 '09 at 0:27): this class add head() and tail() method to file object.

```
class File(file):
    def head(self, lines_2find=1):
        self.seek(0)                            #Rewind file
        return [self.next() for x in xrange(lines_2find)]

    def tail(self, lines_2find=1):  
        self.seek(0, 2)                         #go to end of file
        bytes_in_file = self.tell()             
        lines_found, total_bytes_scanned = 0, 0
        while (lines_2find+1 > lines_found and
               bytes_in_file > total_bytes_scanned): 
            byte_block = min(1024, bytes_in_file-total_bytes_scanned)
            self.seek(-(byte_block+total_bytes_scanned), 2)
            total_bytes_scanned += byte_block
            lines_found += self.read(1024).count('\n')
        self.seek(-total_bytes_scanned, 2)
        line_list = list(self.readlines())
        return line_list[-lines_2find:]
```

Usage:

```
f = File('path/to/file', 'r')
f.head(3)
f.tail(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

most convinient way on my own:

```
LINE_COUNT = 3
print [s for (i, s) in enumerate(open('test.txt')) if i < LINE_COUNT]
```

Solution based on [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)
The function open() supports an iteration interface. The enumerate() covers open() and return tuples (index, item), then we check that we're inside an accepted range (if i < LINE_COUNT) and then simply print the result.

Enjoy the Python. ;)

Comment: This just seems like a slightly more complex alternative to `[next(file) for _ in range(LINE_COUNT)]`.

Answer (score 3):

For first 5 lines, simply do:

```
N=5
with open("data_file", "r") as file:
    for i in range(N):
       print file.next()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that obviously (without looking up esoteric stuff in manuals) works without imports and try/except and works on a fair range of Python 2.x versions (2.2 to 2.6):

```
def headn(file_name, n):
    """Like *x head -N command"""
    result = []
    nlines = 0
    assert n >= 1
    for line in open(file_name):
        result.append(line)
        nlines += 1
        if nlines >= n:
            break
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    rval = headn(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    print rval
    print len(rval)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a really big file, and assuming you want the output to be a numpy array, using np.genfromtxt will freeze your computer. This is so much better in my experience:

```
def load_big_file(fname,maxrows):
'''only works for well-formed text file of space-separated doubles'''

rows = []  # unknown number of lines, so use list

with open(fname) as f:
    j=0        
    for line in f:
        if j==maxrows:
            break
        else:
            line = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
            rows.append(np.array(line, dtype = np.double))
            j+=1
return np.vstack(rows)  # convert list of vectors to array
```

Comment: _If you have a really big file, and assuming you want the output to be a numpy array_ That's quite a unique set of restrictions, I can't really see any advantages to this over the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
f = open("history_export.csv", "r")
line= 5
for x in range(line):
    a = f.readline()
    print(a)
```

Comment: Why not use a context manager? In any case, I don't see how this improves on the many existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to handle the file with less than n-lines by reading the whole file

```
def head(filename: str, n: int):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = [next(f).rstrip() for x in range(n)]
    except StopIteration:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = f.read().splitlines()
    return head_lines
```

Credit go to John La Rooy and Ilian Iliev. Use the function for the best performance with exception handle

Revise 1: Thanks FrankM for the feedback, to handle file existence and read permission we can futher add

```
import errno
import os

def head(filename: str, n: int):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), filename)  
    if not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
        raise PermissionError(errno.EACCES, os.strerror(errno.EACCES), filename)     
   
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = [next(f).rstrip() for x in range(n)]
    except StopIteration:
        with open(filename) as f:
            head_lines = f.read().splitlines()
    return head_lines
```

You can either go with second version or go with the first one and handle the file exception later. The check is quick and mostly free from performance standpoint

Comment: Well this isn't soundproof. Meaning if there is an exception, you try to read the file again, which could throw another exception. This works if the file exists and you got the permissions to read. If not it results in an exception. The accepted answer provides (solution 3) a variant which does the same using ```islice``` (reads the whole file, when it has fewer lines). But your solution is better than variant 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks @FrankM for the feedback, please see my revise answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting at Python 2.6, you can take advantage of more sophisticated functions in the IO base clase.  So the top rated answer above can be rewritten as:

```
    with open("datafile") as myfile:
       head = myfile.readlines(N)
    print head
```

(You don't have to worry about your file having less than N lines since no StopIteration exception is thrown.)

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) N is the number of _bytes_ to read, **not** the number of _lines_.

Comment: N is the number of bytes!

Comment: Wow. Talk about poor naming. The function name mentions `lines` but the argument refers to `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Python 2 & 3:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('/tmp/filename.txt') as inf:
    for line in islice(inf, N, N+M):
        print(line)
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to the [decade-old top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767589/11301900).

Answer (score 0):

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
num_lines = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f: #lines count
    for line in f:
        num_lines += 1

num_lines_input = int (input("Enter line numbers: "))

if num_lines_input <= num_lines:
    f = open(fname, "r")
    for x in range(num_lines_input):
        a = f.readline()
        print(a)

else:
    f = open(fname, "r")
    for x in range(num_lines_input):
        a = f.readline()
        print(a)
        print("Don't have", num_lines_input, " lines print as much as you can")


print("Total lines in the text",num_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another decent solution with a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')

lines = [next(file) for x in range(3)]  # first 3 lines will be in this list

file.close()
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer?!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get first 10 lines:

```
with open('fileName.txt', mode = 'r') as file:
    list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file][:10]
    print(list)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n 3", "passlist"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output, err = p.communicate()

print  output
```

This Method Worked for me

Comment: This isn't really a Python solution, though.

Comment: I do not even understand what is written in your answer. Please add some explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Simply Convert your CSV file object to a list using **list(file_data)**

```
import csv;
with open('your_csv_file.csv') as file_obj:
    file_data = csv.reader(file_obj);
    file_list = list(file_data)
    for row in file_list[:4]:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Will be horribly slow for huge files, since you'll have to load every single line just to get first 4 of them