# read through first N lines of a file in python

Tags: python

Typically, when reading a file, I use the for line n fileobject: construct. Is there a simple way to just loop over the first N (or some arbitrary subset) of lines in a file, so that I don't have to read in the entire file?

Comment: I tried to take the file length and loop through it as if it were a list, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You should always show that you have made some effort when asking questions here. When possible put in actual code for solutions you have tried, and explanations as to how it didn't work. The way your question is phrased makes it look like you are here for free code. Nobody likes a leech

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read first N lines of a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want:

```
file = open('path/to/File.txt', 'r')
for i in range(1,n):
   file.readline()
```

Further information is here avaliable: [Python Input and Output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: You may want to use a different name for the iteration variable; you use `n` for two purposes here.

Comment: What to do, if there are less than n lines in the file ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import itertools

f = open(filename, 'r')
N = 10 # Number of lines to take

for line in itertools.islice(f, N):
    pass # Your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `itertool.islice`, for example you want to read the lines 6 to 10 then:

```
In [66]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
           lines=list(islice(f,5,10,1))
           print lines
```