# Incorrect output while reading text file in Python

Tags: python, file, io, readlines

I need to read the first 30 lines of a file.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines(30)
print len(lines)
```

> 300

am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read first N lines of a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python)

Comment: I looked into that. I don't know why the code above is not working

Comment: How about for a starter check out documentation on what is readlines parameter actually is https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines

Comment: it reads all the lines, see what argument means: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines, the `30` is not the number of lines to read. It is a buffer hint given in *bytes*.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is valid comment but it not solving the problem.

Comment: How so? It explains why the code is not giving the expected output.

Comment: I guess other answers given on the topic are wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments i have decided to give "answer" to the question: how to read first 30 lines from a file. Answer is: `readline()`

```
lines = []
for i in range(30):
    lines.append(f.readline())
```

Done.