# returning value outside a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I have this text file:

```
[admin]# cat /etc/passwd
root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/ksh
daemon:!:1:1::/etc:
bin:!:2:2::/bin:
sys:!:3:3::/usr/sys: 
adm:!:4:4::/var/adm:
uucp:!:5:5::/usr/lib/uucp: 
guest:!:100:100::/home/guest:
nobody:!:4294967294:4294967294::/:
lpd:!:9:4294967294::/:
lp:*:11:11::/var/spool/lp:/bin/false 
invscout:*:200:1::/var/adm/invscout:/usr/bin/ksh
nuucp:*:6:5:uucp login user:/var/spool/uucppublic:/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico
paul:!:201:1::/home/paul:/usr/bin/ksh
jdoe:*:202:1:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/usr/bin/ksh
```

and some code here

```
with open(file) as f2:
            for lines in f2:
                if "cat /etc/passwd" in lines:
                    for i in range(3):
                        cat = f2.readline()
                        print(cat)
```

if it finds the string `"cat /etc/passwd"`, it will store the next couple of lines inside the variable `cat`

output:

```
root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/ksh
daemon:!:1:1::/etc:
bin:!:2:2::/bin:
```

This is the case if I call `cat` from inside the for loop. If I call it outside of the for loop, I only get the last line :

```
bin:!:2:2::/bin:
```

I assume the line  `for i in range(3)` is the reason for this. is there a way I can call `cat` outside the loops and have it return each of the lines I want printed?

Comment: This what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat = []
with open(file) as f2:
    for lines in f2:
        if "cat /etc/passwd" in lines:
            for i in range(3):
                cat.append(f2.readline())

print cat
```

Read about python lists.

Comment: I see my problem. I had done the same thing but had initiated cat as a list inside the loop as opposed to doing so outside of the loop. I keep forgetting the small things as usual.

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration you overwrite the last value of cat.

Inside of the loop, you print each time before you overwrite. Outside of the loop, you only print its last value.

You could store your results in an array

```
with open(file) as f2:
        for lines in f2:
            if "cat /etc/passwd" in lines:
                cat = []
                for i in range(3):
                    cat.append(f2.readline())
                    print cat[i] 

for x in cat:
    print x
```

Comment: -1 This will not work. `cat` will be out of scope at that point. Also, if for some reason the file had multiple lines with `"cat /etc/passwd"` you would lose all previous data collected

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
cat = ''
with open(file) as f2:
            for lines in f2:
                if "cat /etc/passwd" in lines:
                    for i in range(3):
                        cat += f2.readline()
print(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mixing of `iteration` (`for lines in f2`) and `read method` (`f2.readline`) is not nice. I have a other solution with `itertools.islice`, which only uses `iteration`

```
from itertools import islice

with open(file) as f2:
    for line in f2:
        if "cat /etc/passwd" in lines:
            cat = list(islice(f2, 3))

print cat
```

`cat` is a `list` like the answer of Alex