# Python Loop Only Parses First Five Lines of Text File

Tags: python, file, readline

I'm attempting to read and print a `.txt` file line-by-line in Python using the `readline` function. The below code is intended to print out the entire text file line-by-line, but as of right now, it only prints out the first five lines of the text file.

```
filename = input("Enter the name and extension of the file you want to open.")
file = open(filename, "r")
fileline = file.readline()
for line in fileline:
    fileline = fileline.rstrip("\n")
    print(fileline)
    fileline = file.readline()
file.close()
```

I expect the code to print out the entire file line by line, but it currently only prints out the first five lines. What is the bug in the code?

Comment: You should strive for a better title. Imagine a site in which every title was like yours, and what the front page would read like.

Comment: How many characters are there in the first line of the file?

Comment: `for line in fileline` is looping through the characters of the line, not looping through lines.

Comment: Why not try `for line in file: print(line)`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Four on both- I could test it with different ones if you'd like!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried it- it prints the individual digits of the first number on different lines, then stops.

Comment: I think you mean four plus the newline character, totaling five.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I forgot about the newline! Thanks a billion!

Comment: @SamRockitt I edited your post for brevity... you're gonna get a lot of negative points for putting personal language and so much repetitive verbiage in the post... feel free to edit further as you desire, but wanted to explain the reasoning behind the edits.  Also I recommend you put the console output and file contents as you offered.  Please put them as blocks of code, for readability.  Thanks!

Comment: @SamRockitt Also please post the exact wording of the assignment question for clarity.  You keep alluding to it.  Don't bother describing it in your own words... just post the exact question to cut down on the confusion.

Comment: Apparent duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python ... the answer even is the exact same as one of the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read first N lines of a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
for line in fileline:
```

is looping through the characters of `fileline`, which contains the first line of the file. So if the first line has 5 characters, this loop will execute 5 times.

Then inside the loop, you print the line and then read the next line into the `fileline` variable. That has no effect on the loop, which is still iterating over the characters in the first line.

To make the program deliberately print the first 5 lines, you can do:

```
for i in range(5):
    fileline = file.readline()
    if (fileline == ''): #end of file reached
        break
    print(fileline.rtrim('\n'))
```

Or you can iterate over `file`, which automatically reads lines, and use a separate counter variable

```
i = 0
for line in file:
    print(line.rtrim('\n'))
    i += 1
    if i == 5:
        break
```

Comment: `fileline` is the line, `line` is just one character in the line.

Comment: Or `for line,_ in zip(file, range(5)): print(line)`.

Comment: @SamRockitt The newline character is the 5th character.