# Read first N lines of a file in a 2d list. Its not same as for 1d case

Tags: python

I have the following type of data in a text file.

```
15  1  
23  0  
39 -1  
71 -1  
79  1  
95  1  
127 -2  
151  2  
183  1  
191 -1  
239  0  
247  3
```

I want to create a 2d list from the text file as follows. I am able to do that with the code given below with the following result

```
[[15,  1],
[23,  0], 
[39, -1],  
[71, -1],  
[79,  1],
[95,  1], 
[127, -2],  
[151,  2],  
[183,  1], 
[191, -1],  
[239, 0],  
[247, 3]]
```

The problem is that the file contains millions of such data. What do I do to just copy first say 1000 lines at a time? How can I add the conditional statement into my code.

```
with open("path.text") as file:
    R = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read first N lines of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python)

Comment: @Hamms Its not. I tried their solutions their it does not work for 2d array.

Comment: Why are you reading it beforehand instead of processing it on the fly?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am not reading it. Its part of big computation and I need to do it in stages taking may be 10^6 at a time.

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate of that, you just need to adapt the answer to include the little bit of processing you're doing. `with open("path.text") as file: R = [[int(x) for x in next(file).split()] for x in xrange(N)]`

Comment: @Hamms Thanks.. This works. I tried to modify accordingly for almost an hour but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing that, not sure if it's the best.

```
with open("test2.txt") as file:
    R = []
    while len(R) < 1000:
        R.append([int(x) for x in file.readline().split()])
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But now the array contains strings whereas I need integers and R.append(int(file.readline().split())) did not work.

Comment: @Kumarm I changed it to have ints, sorry about that. check it now for it with ints

Comment: @Kumarm Awesome, make sure to accept it if it worked for you :)