# Read n qty rows of delimited txt file in Python

Tags: python, text-files, delimiter, openrowset, structured-data

I have a large txt file that I want to read in python. It's tab delimited. I want to be able to read the headers as well. I saw this stackoverflow site but it doesn't show how to both designate the n qty of rows as well as determine the delimiter and line break: [Read first N lines of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas dataframe will help you do that automatically.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep='\t')
df.head(n=5)  # for the 5 first lines of your file
```

For more info, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: Thanks! I ran into memory issues. Is there a read function that doesn't load the entire file into memory first? I'm looking at a txt file with 45,000,000 records...

Comment: @ScottDavis try using `df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep='\t',low_memory=False)`, or try using chunks. I've never had this problem before, but my files are much smaller. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Lawrence! I used the suggested code and still hit the "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory"