# Can you ask for only 10 trends using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So, I am rewriting this, but I am using Tweepy to get trends, and I want only 10, not the standard, 50 trends. I have tried using other code from websites, ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/read-first-n-lines-of-a-file-in-python), [here](http://www.compciv.org/practicum/shakefiles/d-print-first-5-lines-of-hamlet/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list).) and implementing it, but to no avail. Here is a snippet of code.

```
import time
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(APIKey, APIKeysecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
trends1 = api.trends_place(1, '#')
data = trends1[0] 
trends = data['trends']
names = [trend['name'] for trend in trends]
trendsName = '\n'.join(names)
print(trendsName, file=open("trends.txt", "w"))
```

Comment: Sorry about that! I have updated the post to reflect the rules now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of trends returned by the [`API.trends_place` method](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.trends_place) / [GET trends/place endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place) is not necessarily in order of most trending, so if you want to get the top 10 trends, you'll have to sort by `"tweet_volume"`, e.g.:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_API_KEY, CONSUMER_API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
data = api.trends_place(1, '#')
trends = data[0]["trends"]
# Remove trends with no Tweet volume data
trends = filter(itemgetter("tweet_volume"), trends)
# Alternatively, using 0 during sorting would work as well:
# sorted(trends, key=lambda trend: trend["tweet_volume"] or 0, reverse=True)
sorted_trends = sorted(trends, key=itemgetter("tweet_volume"), reverse=True)
top_10_trend_names = '\n'.join(trend['name'] for trend in sorted_trends[:10])
with open("trends.txt", 'w') as trends_file:
    print(top_10_trend_names, file=trends_file)
```

Note, as the answers and comments for the Stack Overflow questions you linked point out, it's bad practice to leak a file object like in your snippet. See [The Python Tutorial on Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

On the other hand, if you simply want any 10 of the top 50 trends, you can simply index the trends list you already have, e.g.:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_API_KEY, CONSUMER_API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
data = api.trends_place(1, '#')
trends = data[0]["trends"]
ten_trend_names = '\n'.join(trend['name'] for trend in trends[:10])
with open("trends.txt", 'w') as trends_file:
    print(ten_trend_names, file=trends_file)
```