# Fastest way to read and delete N lines in python

Tags: python, file-read, read-write

Fastest way to read and delete `N` lines in python.

First I read the file something like this: (I think this is the best way to read large files: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767513/how-to-read-first-n-lines-of-a-file/1767589#1767589))

```
N = 50
with open("ahref.txt", "r+") as f:
    link_list = [(next(f)).removesuffix("\n") for x in range(N)]
```

after that I run my code:

```
# My code here
```

After that I want to delete the first `N` line (I read it: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file/28057753#28057753)).

```
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-in-a-file/28057753#28057753
with open("target.txt", "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in d:
        if i != "line you want to remove...":
            f.write(i)
    f.truncate()
```

This code doesn't work for me. Because I read only `N` numbers of lines.

I can remove lines:

```
with open("xml\\ahref.txt", "r+") as f:
    N = 5
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(all_lines[N:])
```

But there is a problem with that:

1. I have to read all the lines and after that I have to write all the lines.
   which is not a fast way (There are many ways, but it needs to read all line)

What is the fastest way in terms of performance? because the file is huge.

Comment: I don't think you can truncate the beginning of a file, only the end, so you probably have no choice but to write all the lines again

Comment: Maybe don't use a file format that's not suitable for what you want to do with it?

Comment: @mozway thanks! Is the code I've written is a good approach or can there be even better?

Comment: I think that's pretty good

Comment: `del all_lines[:N]` should be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I am making web crawler.
The file will contain a list of links. As soon as I've crawled N links. I want to delete it.
what method should I use?

Comment: Not sure. Depends on the whole picture. Maybe instead of one huge file, have many smaller files?

Comment: Thanks for `del all_lines[:N]` 
I want to run it inside a loop.
As soon as I've crawled n links, I'll crawl n links again.
That's why I have to keep it in a single file.
In future I will use database.

Answer (score 1):

fastest way is not to read the entire file in memory and use a temporary output file that you can then move over the original file if required

try:

```
N = 50
mode = "r+"
if not os.path.isfile('output'): mode = "w+" 
with open('input', 'r') as fin, open('output', mode) as fout:
    for index, line in enumerate(fout): N += 1
    for index, line in enumerate(fin):
        if index > N: fout.write(line)
        # i haven't tested this you may need index > N or index >= N
```

Comment: This is doing stuff in Python code, though, with quite a bit of work for each line. I doubt this is actually *faster*. Have you measured it?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I measured it and you are correct speed is very similar to reading the entire file the only difference is this approach uses less system resources but in terms of performance they are the same.

Comment: @SomeoneRandom3142 If my script stops, I have to start over from the first line.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Kheersagarpatel i've updated the code to show how you would start from the last line processed, you simply open the previous output file, count the number of lines in that file and continue processing from there.

Comment: @SomeoneRandom3142 But this is not working. I have 20 line so it always save in output file from 7th line. Next time saves from 7th line whereas I want next time from 14th line.

Comment: @Kheersagarpatel what is the initial value of N that you start with,  is it 7?   can you share a sample of your code

Comment: 50 and how to get first 50 in list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237706/discussion-between-someonerandom3142-and-kheersagar-patel).